# Send MultiValueMap params as http link key-value values

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I have this MultiValueMap with params which I would like to send as http link key-value values

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("entityId", "123456");
map.add("amount", "123456");
```

Feign Client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "Staging", url = "https://test.com")
public interface Client {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    SaleResponse performSaleTransaction(@QueryMap MultiValueMap<String, String> params);
}
```

But I get exception:

```
feign.FeignException$BadRequest: [400 Bad Request] during [POST] to [https://test.com] [Client#performSaleTransaction(String,MultiValueMap)]: [{"result":{"code":"200.300.404","description":"invalid or missing parameter","parameterErrors":[{"name":"entityId","value":null,"message":"invalid or missing parameter"}]},"buildNumber":"......","timestamp":"2021-05-23 12:31:52+0000","ndc":"......"}]
        at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:195)
```

Looks like Feign cannot convert properly the values from the `MultiValueMap`. DO you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found in sources

```
if (MAP_STRING_WILDCARD.equals(bodyType)) {
      data = (Map<String, Object>) object;
```

```
MAP_STRING_WILDCARD is Map<String,?>
```

try to change u MultiValueMap<String, String> to Map<String,?>

Comment: Work really fine!